# Display different attributes of an object in different columns in data grid

Tags: apache-flex, object, datagrid

Can anyone please tell me how to display different attributes of an object in different columns in datagrid in flex?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to read the basic help page for flex DataGrid ?

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=dpcontrols_6.html

Here is a sample from the live docs:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- dpcontrols/DataGridVisibleColumn.mxml -->
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" >
   <mx:DataGrid id="myDG" width="350"> 
      <mx:dataProvider>
         <mx:ArrayCollection>
            <mx:source>
               <mx:Object Artist="Pavement" Price="11.99" 
                  Album="Slanted and Enchanted" />
               <mx:Object Artist="Pavement" 
                  Album="Brighten the Corners" Price="11.99" />
            </mx:source>
         </mx:ArrayCollection>
      </mx:dataProvider>
      <mx:columns>
         <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Artist" />
         <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Album" />
         <mx:DataGridColumn id="price" dataField="Price" visible="false"/>
      </mx:columns>
   </mx:DataGrid>

   <!-- The column id property specifies the column to show.-->
   <mx:Button label="Toggle Price Column" 
      click="price.visible = !price.visible;" />
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: I already went through it but it does not address my question.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not think I missundestood your question. Maybe you expressed yourself in a wrong way ?! Please give a sample of code or data model and tell us more exactly what you want!!!!

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding but I got the solution. I was trying to display the objects that I got from java in the data grid flex but was having problem displaying the values of the attributes of the object in the data grid. I used
contractList=event as ArrayCollection instead of contractList=event.result as ArrayCollection;. Thanks